# Merging folders with a script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal, mv

I have a list of 417 folder paths that I need to merge in a specific order so that files in them overwrite each other. I'll probably need to do it again in the future when I make changes to the folder so I am definitely not doing this manually, I'd like to learn how to write a script that does this.

Also if the script can convert everything to lowercase that'd be great too, what I did for these was I zipped them with no compression then unzipped them with -LL but it'd be nice if I don't have to do that again since it took awhile (17gb).

The list is just like this

"/path/"

"/path/"

"/path/"

(if anyone's curious this is for merging a bunch of mods for morrowind/openmw)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
while IFS= read -r dir
do
    cp -f "$dir"/* target
done < list
```

where `list` is the list of directories
and `target` is the directory that you want to copy the files to. 
The files in the directories appearing later in the list
will overwrite files in the directories appearing earlier in the list —
`cp -f` specifies the “force overwrite” option to the copy program. 
This assumes:

- Directory names do not contain newlines. 
  (You wouldn’t be able to list them in a simple text file if they did.)
- The list file does not actually contain quotes.
- Each directory has only (plain) files,
  not subdirectories or special things.
- No filenames begin with **`.`**.

Comment: Does this work if the directories have spaces in their names?

Comment: Yes, because of the `IFS=` before the `read` and the double quotes in ``"$dir"``.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r $(<sources) target/
```

should work.

This assumes that the paths are listed in the file `sources`.

Each path may be that of a directory or file, but no path in the `sources` file may contain any whitespace (space, tab, newline, etc.) or shell globbing character (such as `*` or `?`), and they should not be quoted (unless the actual name contains a quote).

You could also use something like

```
xargs -t -Isrc cp -r src target/ <sources
```

This would allow for more exotic filenames, but not for filenames with newlines.

---

The following is a short `bash` script that converts a set of filenames to lower-case (the `echo` should be removed to perform an actual renaming, it's there so that you can see what would happen).

```
#!/bin/bash

for path in "$@"; do
    dir="${path%/*}"
    name="${path##*/}"

    if [[ ! "$path" -ef "$dir/${name,,}" ]]; then
        echo mv "$path" "$dir/${name,,}"
    fi
done
```

The `-ef` test returns true if the two paths refer to the same file (in which case the renaming shouldn't happen). The `${name,,}` variable substitution is what does the actual lower-casing.

You may apply this to a directory like this:

```
$ find target -type f -exec bash tolower.sh {} +
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for directories that do have spaces? Or is there a way to convert spaces to _ in directories?

Comment: @user234366 The `xargs` solution allows for spaces in filenames. And my last script also allows for spaces in filenames when converting them to lower-case.

Comment: The `xargs` solution allows for directory names that *contain* space(s) after the first character, but not directory names that ***begin with* a space**.